# Fill empty month data Carbon Parse Extract

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get data count grouped by its `created_at` column.

I tried this:

```
$data = User::all()->groupBy(function($date) {
    return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('Y M');
});

foreach ($data as $key=> $value) {
    $res[$key] = count($value);
}
```

and I got result like this when I return the `$res`

```
"message": "Data Fetched",
"res": {
    "2021 Jan": 1,
    "2021 Mar": 6,
    "2021 May": 30,
    "2021 Jun": 24
}
```

}

any idea how to fill the empty month with 0 ? becuse no data created at that time. Thankyou in advance

expected result

```
"message": "Data Fetched",
"res": {
    "2021 Jan": 1,
    "2021 Feb": 0,
    "2021 Mar": 6,
    "2021 Apr": 0,
    "2021 May": 30,
    "2021 Jun": 24
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```html
$hoge = 2021/Feb;
foreach ($data as $key=> $value){
            while($hoge != $key){
                $res[$hoge] = 0;
                $hoge = $hoge + 1month;
            }
            $res[$key] = count($value);
        }
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.